# Как получить ответ от бота при нажатии inline кнопок Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

как получить ответ от бота при нажатии inline кнопок , например
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот такую , функцию нажатие кнопок реализовал , но никак не могу реализовать эту функцию , пж помогите

вот сам код если чё -

async def press_inline_button_by_link(client):
link = input("Введите ссылку на сообщение с inline кнопкой: ")
button_index = int(input("Введите индекс кнопки для нажатия (начиная с 1): ")) - 1

match = re.match(r'https://t.me/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(\d+)', link)

if match:
username, message_id = match.groups()
message_id = int(message_id)

messages = await client.get_messages(username, ids=message_id)

message = messages[0] if isinstance(messages, list) else messages

buttons = [button for row in message.reply_markup.rows for button in row.buttons]

inline_button = buttons[button_index]

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=username, incoming=True))
async def handle_response(event):
print("Получен ответ на нажатие кнопки:")
print(event.message.text)

await message.click(button_index)

await asyncio.sleep(5)

client.remove_event_handler(handle_response)
else:
print("Некорректная ссылка на сообщение")

await press_inline_button_by_link(client)

Comment: Приведите код в правильно форматированном виде -- в синтаксисе питона важны отступы, а у вас они все потеряны.  И проясните вопрос, что именно вы хотите получить от функции.